# Edge Browser - iframe.document.open not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, iframe, microsoft-edge

We have some functionality for exporting data to an excel file.
When the 'export' button is clicked, some client-side javascript is called, firstly checking the client browser version, and based on this, deciding which way to render the excel document.
It is working in Chrome & Firefox & IE11 when tested locally.
However, when I remotely test using a windows 10 machine running Edge browser, the excel is not rendered.

I might add that my local machine is a Win7 machine and Im running VS2012 and IE11. The remote machine is Win10 with Edge, hence the need to test remotely.
I've tried the emulation in IE11 F12 dev tools but cant replicate the Edge error there.

An error of 'undefined or null reference' is thrown for 'open' when using the following code:

```
excelIFrame.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                    excelIFrame.document.write(sHTML);
                    excelIFrame.document.close();
                    excelIFrame.focus();
                    excelIFrame.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Spreadsheet.xls");
```

The iframe exists in the html and is not added dynamically.

```
<iframe id="excelIFrame" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

I have tried the following possible solutions to get this working, to no avail -

**Possible Solution 1:** Same 'undefined or null reference error when assigning the document to a temp var

```
var doc = excelIFrame.document;
                        doc.open("txt/html", "replace");
                        doc.write(sHTML);
                        doc.close();
                        doc.focus();
                        doc.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Spreadsheet.xls");
```

**Possible Solution 2:** Using the contentWindow property of the iFrame. No error thrown, it just opens 'about:blank' containing no content.

```
excelIFrame.contentWindow.contents = sHTML;
                    excelIFrame.src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';
```

Totally at a loss with this at this stage.
The page is an angularJS web page.
From reading up on it, I'm aware the document.open is problematic in edge when using iframes. But the following link [document.open fails in an iframe](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1822924/in-an-iframe-document-open-fails-whereas-var-doc-document-doc-open-succeeds) I felt would solve the problem.
Any thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to others who are searching for it.

```
    //For Edge browser ….. U have to write separate logic for each browser
    if (ua.match(/Edge/)){
       var blob = new Blob([sHTML], {type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel'});
       window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "P2P_Report_"+new Date().getTime()+".xls");
    }
```